# Symfony 4 validation constraints alternative

Tags: symfony, validation

Is there a simple way to construct an alternative of validation constriants, like below?

```
/**
 * @Assert\Or(
 *    @Assert\MinLength(4),
 *    @Assert\Regex("XYZ")
 * )
 */
 $column;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `CallbackValidator` to implement an method on the Class that will do the validation.

Or implement a custom Validator yourself (useful if you need the same validation construct on an other class )

https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html

Comment: By simple I mean like this non-existent "OR" constraint. There is an undocumented "Composite" constraint, but since it is NOT documented, I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the question. Updated my answer. I was like "oh they have implemented the OR finally!"  not realising it's pseudo codde

Answer (score 2):

Although this does not answer the question directly (as this solution did not exist in Symfony 4), this might however be useful for others arriving here from Google years later.

Since Symfony 5.1 there is an [AtLeastOneOf](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/AtLeastOneOf.html) constraint, which does exactly that - passes the validation if at least one of the subconstraints is satisfied. Example from their documentation:

> The following constraints ensure that:
>
> - the password of a Student either contains # or is at least 10 characters long;
> - the grades of a Student is an array which contains at least 3 elements or that each element is greater than or equal to 5.

```yaml
# config/validator/validation.yaml
App\Entity\Student:
    properties:
        password:
            - AtLeastOneOf:
                - Regex: '/#/'
                - Length:
                    min: 10
        grades:
            - AtLeastOneOf:
                - Count:
                    min: 3
                - All:
                    - GreaterThanOrEqual: 5
```